# Vanilla JS - Execute code after an element is clicked

Tags: javascript, callback, click

Is it possible to trigger a callback function after an element is clicked with 'myElement.click()'? When I look around, all solutions are jQuery related or are combined with an addEventListener like this:

```
myElement.addEventListener('click', function() {});
```

**I'll try to explain my situation as good as possible so things are clear**

I have a third party plugin that writes the 'lat' and 'lon' values into a text field when you click it's button. That button is so ugly that I want replace it by my own styled button.

So what I've done is hide that third party button with CSS ('display: none'). Then, I've created a new 'crosshairs' button:

```
  // Make a crosshairs button
  var crosshairs = document.createElement('i');
  crosshairs.id = 'crosshairs';
  crosshairs.className += 'Filter-crosshairs fas fa-crosshairs';
  crosshairs.title = 'Laad mijn huidige locatie';
```

Then, for every appearence of that third party button, I've put my own created button before it:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < currentLocationButtons.length; i++) {
        // Put my button before the (hidden) third party button
        var currentLocationButtonParent = currentLocationButtons[i].parentNode;
        currentLocationButtonParent.insertBefore(crosshairs, currentLocationButtons[i]);
...
      }
```

Now, for every 'Filter-crosshairs'-button that is clicked, that click should be passed to that hidden button. This 'for'-loop goes into the previous'for'-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentLocationButtons.length; i++) {
    currentLocationButtons[i].click();
}
```

So here's my problem: I'm not able to make a callback function that waits until the third party plugin have set the 'lat' and 'lon' value into the text field.
If I go on coding under the 'click()', I must push the button twice before it works (user friendliness = beneath 0).

Does anybody have an idea how I can do a callback? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

> So here's my problem: I'm not able to make a callback function that waits until the third party plugin have set the 'lat' and 'lon' value into the text field.

Consider using a deffered event listener (similar to JQuery's `.on`) like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // check some criteria that the target is the one you actually want
    if(event.target.className === 'someClass'){
        // do something here

    }
});
```

this way the event listener is attached to the document, and does not need your actual target to be on the page yet.

nb. you can also manually dispatch events like so but YMMV if you need to support older IE (though there are polyfils for this):

```js
yourElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the extreem quick respons Gavin! It's a whole new way for handling clicks so I'm very glad to read your help :) I've already tried it, but the old button isn't triggered for now. I guess something else goes wrong now. I'll keep you posted ;)